# Allow user to choose option from menu with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm working on part of a program which presents a menu of 3 options to the user. I want to allow the user to enter their menu choice (1-3) after which the menu appears again and allows the user to enter another choice and repeats this process for a total of n times which the user also inputs prior to the menu.

The program is just printing the menu 3 times in a row rather than in n separate iterations but I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
n = int(input('Please enter the number of iterations:'))

for i in range(0,n):

    print('Enter 1 for choice 1\n')

    print('Enter 2 for choice 2\n')

    print('Enter 3 for choice 3\n')

    choice = int(input('Enter your choice:'))

    if (choice == 1):

    ....
    ....

    else:
        print('Invalid choice')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your code to handle the choice inside the loop:

```
n = int(input('Please enter the number of iterations:'))

for i in range(0,n):

    print('Enter 1 for choice 1\n')

    print('Enter 2 for choice 2\n')

    print('Enter 3 for choice 3\n')

    choice = int(input('Enter your choice:'))

    if (choice == 1):

        ....
        ....

    else:
        print('Invalid choice')
```

Answer (score 1):

Indent the following piece of code, 4 spaces to the right:

```
if (choice == 1):
    ...
    ...
else:
    print('Invalid choice')
```

But if I may suggest a better implementation of what you are trying to do, then define a function which can handle a non-numeric user input, and in addition, take those prints outside the `for` loop:

```
def getUserInput(msg):
    while True:
        print msg
        try:
            return int(input(msg))
        except Exception,error:
            print error

n = getUserInput('Please enter the number of iterations:')

print 'Enter 1 for choice 1'
print 'Enter 2 for choice 2'
print 'Enter 3 for choice 3'

while n > 0:
    choice = getUserInput('Enter your choice:')
    if choice == 1:
        ...
        n -= 1
    elif choice == 2:
        ...
        n -= 1
    elif choice == 3:
        ...
        n -= 1
    else:
        print 'Invalid choice'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun: I've rewritten this to introduce some more advanced ideas (program structure, use of `enumerate()`, first-class functions, etc).

```
# assumes Python 3.x
from collections import namedtuple

def get_int(prompt, lo=None, hi=None):
    while True:
        try:
            val = int(input(prompt))
            if (lo is None or lo <= val) and (hi is None or val <= hi):
                return val
        except ValueError:   # input string could not be converted to int
            pass

def do_menu(options):
    print("\nWhich do you want to do?")
    for num,option in enumerate(options, 1):
        print("{num}: {label}".format(num=num, label=option.label))
    prompt = "Please enter the number of your choice (1-{max}): ".format(max=len(options))
    choice = get_int(prompt, 1, len(options)) - 1
    options[choice].fn()    # call the requested function

def kick_goat():
    print("\nBAM! The goat didn't like that.")

def kiss_duck():
    print("\nOOH! The duck liked that a lot!")

def call_moose():
    print("\nYour trombone sounds rusty.")

Option = namedtuple("Option", ["label", "fn"])
options = [
    Option("Kick a goat", kick_goat),
    Option("Kiss a duck", kiss_duck),
    Option("Call a moose", call_moose)
]

def main():
    num = get_int("Please enter the number of iterations: ")
    for i in range(num):
        do_menu(options)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to develop a python program that asks several intervals of integer numbers to the user
(negative or positive numbers). Each time, the user should have an option to either provide a new
interval or quit the program. The intervals will form lists of numbers and have a limit of -999 or 999.
An interval is defined as a continuous sequence of integer numbers. For every break in the continuity
of the integer numbers, you assume a new interval.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).